# Problem passing Razor Value to js <script> inside a view mvc asp.net ef

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I' ll start this by saying that yesterday the code was working fine. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I think this should be working but it doesn't so thank you in advance for all the help:

I have this view and I' m trying to implement Paypal Paylemnet. This is the script section in the view:

```
    <div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")



    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=EUR" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                shape: 'rect',
                color: 'gold',
                layout: 'vertical',
                label: 'paypal',

            },

            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                var totalPrice = @Model.OrderDetailsVMs.Sum(x => x.TotalPricePerOrderDetails);
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{ "amount": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": (totalPrice + 10), "breakdown": { "item_total": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": totalPrice }, "shipping": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": 10 }, "tax_total": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": 0 } } } }]
                });
            },

            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            },

            onError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
    </script>
}
```

The problem comes in this line :

```
var totalPrice = @Model.OrderDetailsVMs.Sum(x => x.TotalPricePerOrderDetails);
```

The value doesn't pass from the razor to the js var. If I hardcode a value to var totalPrice, for example if I write:

```
var totalPrice = 3.33;
```

everything works fine. Also, I can display the value of the

```
@Model.OrderDetailsVMs.Sum(x => x.TotalPricePerOrderDetails);
```

and it works, so I know that the value passes there. Can anyone think of why the value doesn't pass inside the script?

P.S I get the same problem even if I try to pass it through an id.

Thank you all in advance.

Edit : Fixed it was using a decimal value with more than two digits after the .

Comment: What value does it print? Is it blank or 0? Try enclosing it in parenthesis "@(Model.OrderDetailsVMs.Sum(x => x.TotalPricePerOrderDetails));" Are you sure its valued? You can shove a .ToArray in there "Model.OrderDetailsVMs.ToArray().Sum" to check.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it I was passing a decimal and it only accepted values with two digits after the .